# Saving both polymorphic relationships at the same time in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism

I want to correctly save both polymorphic relationships at the same time. The code below works, but I feel it could be a lot cleaner as I presume the two `update()` methods are calling the database twice.

A `NewsModule::class` can have different module items; `VideoModule`, `TextModule`, `ImageModule`, and a few more. Each containing their own content to be attached to the parent `NewsModule`.

As mentioned, the code works so the relationships are set up correctly, but I'm convinced there's a cleaner way of saving both at the same time.

I'm also open to suggestions about cleaning up the `if` statements too. But maybe that's another post.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $module = NewsModule::find($id);

    if ($module->type === 'text') {
        $content = TextModule::find($module->content_id);
    } elseif ($module->type === 'image') {
        $content = ImageModule::find($module->content_id);
    };

    $module->update($request->all());
    $content->update($request->all());

    return fractal()
        ->item($module, new NewsModuleTransformer)
        ->parseIncludes(['content'])
        ->toArray();
}
```

Updated (more code by request)...

Structure:

```
news_modules
    - id
    - content_id
    - content_type
    - etc

text_modules
    - id
    - content
    - etc

image_modules
    - id
    - image_id
    - etc
```

NewsModule:

```
class NewsModule extends Model
{
    public function content()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

All item modules:

```
class TextModule extends Model
{
    public function newsmodules()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(NewsModule::class, 'content');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both module and content relate to the same table? Can you elaborate your table structure?

Comment: @paras I've just added more the model structure above

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're saying both updates can be a single query but they are two different tables. So how do you expect them to be a single query?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible or not, hence the question. I was curious if there was a to update NewsItem and also save the child relation too. Something like `$module->content->saveBoth($data)` which I know is not a method. This is the first time working on a polymorphic relation and wondered if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: In my opinion, its not possible. Not anything to do with Laravel or at the application level, it's not even possible with mysql :)

Comment: Great. Now I can focus on tidying up those `if` statements. Thanks. :)

Comment: No probs, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $modele = NewsModule::find($id);

    $module->update($request->all());

    $module->content->update($request->all());

    return fractal()
        ->item($module, new NewsModuleTransformer)
        ->parseIncludes(['content'])
        ->toArray();
}
```

That will run 4 queries total.  1 for each module to retrieve and another to update.  That can be cut down to 3 like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $modele = NewsModule::find($id);

    $module->update($request->all());

    $module->content()->update($request->all());

    return fractal()
        ->item($module, new NewsModuleTransformer)
        ->parseIncludes(['content'])
        ->toArray();
}
```

The downside to `$module->content()->update($request->all());` is it will throw an error if there is anything in `$request->all()` that isn't a column in that content model or there is an array as a value.  You can avoid that by just calling `update()` on the `$fillable` properties (if you have them defined) of the related model like:

```
    $fillable = $module->content()->getRelated()->getFillable();
    $module->content()->update($request->only($fillable));
```

This way will also not fire any model event listeners you have since you are never retrieving the model from the database.

To take everything one step further, look into [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding).  In your `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('news', App\NewsModule::class);
}
```

This way 'news' will always resolve to an instance of `NewsModule` when using it as a route parameter.  So your route would be something like:

```
Route::match(['patch', 'put'], '/news/{news}', 'NewsController@update');
```

So in your `update` method you could resolve the model by just type hinting it in the method allowing you to do:

```
public function update(Request $request, NewsModule $news)
{
    $news->update($request->all());

    $news->content->update($request->all());

    return fractal()
        ->item($news, new NewsModuleTransformer)
        ->parseIncludes(['content'])
        ->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, Route Model Binding won't work for me here because the slugs are dynamic `/{pageSlug}/{itemSlug}`. However, your second code block will make my code cleaner and remove some of my `if` statements too. So for that reason, I'll mark it answered. The full explanation helped too :)

Comment: If you're using dynamic slugs, you can customize your route model binding resolution logic and resolve your models however you want: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic OR customize the key name used to resolve the model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#customizing-the-key-name